# Eclipse cannot find raw resource

Tags: android, resources

I have a raw resource in res/raw, but I cannot find it using

```
context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.mystore);
```

But it is generated in R file

```
public static final class raw {
    public static final int mystore=0x7f040000;
}
```

I tried cleaning up, refreshing it, restarting Eclipes, but nothing works.

Comment: have You checked imports? do you have import <your_package>.R ?

Comment: Check the import is "urpackage.R" or "androidpackage.R"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you import `yourpackage.R` and not `android.R`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

`InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.mystore);`